# Hex grid with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently trying to create a hex grid using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) and the [hexbin plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/hexbin) for [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). The problem I'm having is that I always have empty hexagons or entire empty rows in my grid instead of all hexagons nice together.

Any ideas how to fix this?

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/AtjDB/1/):

```
var margin = {
    top: 80,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 80
},
width = $(window).width() - margin.left - margin.right,
height = $(window).height() - 28 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var points = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        points.push([Math.floor(width * j / 12), Math.floor(height * i / 8)]);
    }
}

var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
    .size([width, height])
    .radius((width / 12) / 2);

var svg = d3.select($("#grid").get(0)).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".hexagon")
    .data(hexbin(points))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "hexagon")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    return hexbin.hexagon();
})
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
})
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return "#dcdcdc"; //color(d.length); 
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your points data so that, when hexagons are added, the translation is not pushing them one hexagon too far right or one row too far down:

Something like this:

```
var points = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        points.push([Math.floor(width * j / 14), Math.floor(height * i / 11)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but if you change the resolution of your screen the grid should always show the same amount of hexogons. With this solution this isn't the case.

Comment: Yes, the plugin seems a little brittle when you change the resolution of the screen - you can hack it a bit like so: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/WC7ue/2/

Comment: How did you get the 1.8 and 1.5 numbers for the offsetting?

Comment: @JesusNoland - some trial and error based on proportions of the hexagon.

Comment: Gotcha, yea I had to do the same and found that 1.5 worked for both the x and the y. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: 1.5 has some mathematical reasons - see [this excellent article](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) for everything you could ever want to know about hexagon grids, including code samples for things like move distance and line of sight around obstacles within the grid.